# How to use ansible without ssh keys on openstack instances?

Tags: ansible, openstack, provisioning

I would like to use ansible to roll out updates on servers I have running in a private openstack cloud.  However I would like to do so without copying an ssh key into these servers.  Instead I want to set my openstack password (as that's all I need to ssh into an instance from my company machines) as variables with some `vars_prompt` and then have ansible use those to ssh into my instances and run tasks.

How would I do this?

**Sidenote:** I feel like this post might be a duplicate based on how general this question is, so I will delete it if there is another post solving this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it. `ansible_password` can be set on those hosts in your inventory (preferably using ansible vault with host_vars/group_vars dirs so the passwords aren't sitting there in cleartext). Then just run `ansible-playbook` with `--ask-vault-pass` and you're good to go.

Comment: Yep that worked great all I had to do to run ansible is run it with `ansible servers -m ping --ask-pass`.  I did find the bug that running ansible with `--ask-pass` didn't ask me to verify the authenticity of my host machine and add its fingerprint.  So to get around this I had to run a command through ssh to verify my host machine first.